# Adding values to list of list of tuples and finally convert to list of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

I want to add unique values to every tuple in a list of lists. The list looks like below:

```
    [[('While', 'IN', 'Entity'),
  ('applying', 'VBG', 'O'),
  ('opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
  ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  ('form', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  ('should', 'MD', 'O'),
  ('we', 'PRP', 'O'),
  ('use', 'VB', 'Entity'),
  ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  ('decimal', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  ('or', 'CC', 'Entity'),
  ('double', 'JJ', 'Entity'),
  ('value', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  ('?', '.', 'O')],
 [('I', 'PRP', 'O'),
  ('want', 'VBP', 'O'),
  ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
  ('use', 'VB', 'Entity'),
  ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  ('trackbar', 'NN', 'O'),
  ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
  ('change', 'VB', 'Entity'),
  ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  ('forms', 'JJ', 'Entity'),
  ('opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  ('.', '.', 'O')]]
```

I trying to get the below output:

```
c = [(1, 'While', 'IN', 'Entity'),
  (1, 'applying', 'VBG', 'O'),
  (1, 'opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  (1, 'to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
  (1, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  (1, 'form', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  (1, 'should', 'MD', 'O'),
  (1, 'we', 'PRP', 'O'),
  (1, 'use', 'VB', 'Entity'),
  (1, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  (1, 'decimal', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  (1, 'or', 'CC', 'Entity'),
  (1, 'double', 'JJ', 'Entity'),
  (1, 'value', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  (1, '?', '.', 'O'),
  (2, 'I', 'PRP', 'O'),
  (2, 'want', 'VBP', 'O'),
  (2, 'to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
  (2, 'use', 'VB', 'Entity'),
  (2, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  (2, 'trackbar', 'NN', 'O'),
  (2, 'to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
  (2, 'change', 'VB', 'Entity'),
  (2, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  (2, 'forms', 'JJ', 'Entity'),
  (2, 'opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  (2, '.', '.', 'O')]
```

The number increment should be happened for every list (number should remain same for tuples belonging to a list) and should finally output as the above list of tuples.

By doing this, I would be able to achieve the following:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(c, columns = ['a','b','c','d']) 


    a   b        c  d
0   1   While   IN  Entity
1   1   applying    VBG O
2   1   opacity NN  Entity
3   1   to  TO  Entity
4   1   a   DT  Entity
5   1   form    NN  Entity
6   1   should  MD  O
7   1   we  PRP O
8   1   use VB  Entity
9   1   a   DT  Entity
10  1   decimal NN  Entity
11  1   or  CC  Entity
12  1   double  JJ  Entity
13  1   value   NN  Entity
14  1   ?   .   O
15  2   I   PRP O
16  2   want    VBP O
17  2   to  TO  Entity
18  2   use VB  Entity
19  2   a   DT  Entity
20  2   trackbar    NN  O
21  2   to  TO  Entity
22  2   change  VB  Entity
23  2   a   DT  Entity
24  2   forms   JJ  Entity
25  2   opacity NN  Entity
26  2   .   .   O
```

I'm trying to do with list-zip functions:

```
list(zip(range(len(a)),a))
```

which is giving me the following result:

```
[(0,
  [('While', 'IN', 'Entity'),
   ('applying', 'VBG', 'O'),
   ('opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'),
   ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
   ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
   ('form', 'NN', 'Entity'),
   ('should', 'MD', 'O'),
   ('we', 'PRP', 'O'),
   ('use', 'VB', 'Entity'),
   ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
   ('decimal', 'NN', 'Entity'),
   ('or', 'CC', 'Entity'),
   ('double', 'JJ', 'Entity'),
   ('value', 'NN', 'Entity'),
   ('?', '.', 'O')]),
 (1,
  [('I', 'PRP', 'O'),
   ('want', 'VBP', 'O'),
   ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
   ('use', 'VB', 'Entity'),
   ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
   ('trackbar', 'NN', 'O'),
   ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
   ('change', 'VB', 'Entity'),
   ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
   ('forms', 'JJ', 'Entity'),
   ('opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'),
   ('.', '.', 'O')])]
```

But unable to proceed further with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't *change* tuples, you can only create new.

You should iterate over existing list, creating new tuple with index prepended to old data, and append resulting tuple to new list.

```
result = []
for index, inner_list in enumerate(lst, 1):
    for inner_tuple in inner_list:
        result.append((index, *inner_tuple))
```

[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) gives you ability to iterate over sequence, and have indexes at the same time. Optional "start" arg will help simplify logic.

`((index, *inner_tuple))` creates new tuple with `index` and everything from `inner_tuple` expanded. This works in python 3 only, tho.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop and the **[enumerate method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)** you can iterate over the list of tuples and get the desired output.

**Ex:**

```
a =  [[('While', 'IN', 'Entity'),
  ('applying', 'VBG', 'O'),
  ('opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
  ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  ('form', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  ('should', 'MD', 'O'),
  ('we', 'PRP', 'O'),
  ('use', 'VB', 'Entity'),
  ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  ('decimal', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  ('or', 'CC', 'Entity'),
  ('double', 'JJ', 'Entity'),
  ('value', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  ('?', '.', 'O')],
 [('I', 'PRP', 'O'),
  ('want', 'VBP', 'O'),
  ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
  ('use', 'VB', 'Entity'),
  ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  ('trackbar', 'NN', 'O'),
  ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
  ('change', 'VB', 'Entity'),
  ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
  ('forms', 'JJ', 'Entity'),
  ('opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'),
  ('.', '.', 'O')]]

res = []
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    for j in v:
        res.append(tuple([i+1] + list(j)))

print res
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 'While', 'IN', 'Entity'), (1, 'applying', 'VBG', 'O'), (1, 'opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'), (1, 'to', 'TO', 'Entity'), (1, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity'), (1, 'form', 'NN', 'Entity'), (1, 'should', 'MD', 'O'), (1, 'we', 'PRP', 'O'), (1, 'use', 'VB', 'Entity'), (1, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity'), (1, 'decimal', 'NN', 'Entity'), (1, 'or', 'CC', 'Entity'), (1, 'double', 'JJ', 'Entity'), (1, 'value', 'NN', 'Entity'), (1, '?', '.', 'O'), (2, 'I', 'PRP', 'O'), (2, 'want', 'VBP', 'O'), (2, 'to', 'TO', 'Entity'), (2, 'use', 'VB', 'Entity'), (2, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity'), (2, 'trackbar', 'NN', 'O'), (2, 'to', 'TO', 'Entity'), (2, 'change', 'VB', 'Entity'), (2, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity'), (2, 'forms', 'JJ', 'Entity'), (2, 'opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'), (2, '.', '.', 'O')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a double `for` loop in a list comprehension, using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to produce the indices.

```
data = [
    [
        ('While', 'IN', 'Entity'),
        ('applying', 'VBG', 'O'),
        ('opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'),
        ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
        ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
        ('form', 'NN', 'Entity'),
        ('should', 'MD', 'O'),
        ('we', 'PRP', 'O'),
        ('use', 'VB', 'Entity'),
        ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
        ('decimal', 'NN', 'Entity'),
        ('or', 'CC', 'Entity'),
        ('double', 'JJ', 'Entity'),
        ('value', 'NN', 'Entity'),
        ('?', '.', 'O')
    ],
    [
        ('I', 'PRP', 'O'),
        ('want', 'VBP', 'O'),
        ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
        ('use', 'VB', 'Entity'),
        ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
        ('trackbar', 'NN', 'O'),
        ('to', 'TO', 'Entity'),
        ('change', 'VB', 'Entity'),
        ('a', 'DT', 'Entity'),
        ('forms', 'JJ', 'Entity'),
        ('opacity', 'NN', 'Entity'),
        ('.', '.', 'O')
    ]
]

newdata = [(i,) + tup for i, lst in enumerate(data, 1) for tup in lst]
for row in newdata:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
(1, 'While', 'IN', 'Entity')
(1, 'applying', 'VBG', 'O')
(1, 'opacity', 'NN', 'Entity')
(1, 'to', 'TO', 'Entity')
(1, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity')
(1, 'form', 'NN', 'Entity')
(1, 'should', 'MD', 'O')
(1, 'we', 'PRP', 'O')
(1, 'use', 'VB', 'Entity')
(1, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity')
(1, 'decimal', 'NN', 'Entity')
(1, 'or', 'CC', 'Entity')
(1, 'double', 'JJ', 'Entity')
(1, 'value', 'NN', 'Entity')
(1, '?', '.', 'O')
(2, 'I', 'PRP', 'O')
(2, 'want', 'VBP', 'O')
(2, 'to', 'TO', 'Entity')
(2, 'use', 'VB', 'Entity')
(2, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity')
(2, 'trackbar', 'NN', 'O')
(2, 'to', 'TO', 'Entity')
(2, 'change', 'VB', 'Entity')
(2, 'a', 'DT', 'Entity')
(2, 'forms', 'JJ', 'Entity')
(2, 'opacity', 'NN', 'Entity')
(2, '.', '.', 'O')
```